# Why TagHelpers in Asp.net Core 3.1 is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have problem with Asp.net Core `TagHelpers` I read the other questions asked in StackOverFlow but they didn't help out.

for example when I write this code in my razor page :

```
<a asp-page="/P" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</a>
```

Note that my `/P` page is in same directory with the page i used the code.

So I runned the project and headed to my page to see the `Click Me` button when I click on it , it redirects me to the current page , and the `asp-page` tagHelper isn't working wroperly

i inspected the `Click Me` button and seen this code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href>Click Me</a>
```

you can see the `asp-page` TagHelper just created the empty `href` in my Tag `a` ( the TagHelpers not working in all Of my Project ) and the `/P` page is the route that i defined for a page ( I tested it without route and with route ) both of tests failed and not working.

my Project Have the `Identity 3.1` , so if i go to my `Register` page in `Identity` area , the TagHelpers working there , tut in my Razors they don't work :(
my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file is below:
[The _ViewImports.cshtml File ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gWS2.png)

i tried to put `*,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in Double quotations but they didn't help.

Comment: You Must NOT Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In The English Language!

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way. asp-page denote page name only and asp-route for passing route parameters :

```
<a asp-page="pagename" asp-route-parameterId="@Model.parameterId" asp-route-ContentId="0" title="Add Content" class="glossybutton addcontentbtn">Add Content</a>
```

Comment: Its now Working , My asp-page Is not Working and it puts just (href) without any address in the tag used , i tried to update the nuget packages but they didn't help out

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: No , The Problem Is Fixed , i created a project of type (Web Application) In My Solution And Tested the taghelper there , that worked out fine so i removed the project and checked my first project , now it's working fine . i don't know why that problem occured & FIXED :)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Is Fixed

I Tried to create a project with ( Web Application ) type and tested my codes there and the codes worked fine.

So i removed the project and edited my `_ViewImports.cshtml` File And Placed The `using` and `namespace` in the file , so the problem is fixed.